# Unable to compare 2 sharepoint site url in powershell script

Tags: powershell

Hi i need to compare 2 sharepoint site urls using powershell script. So that once the url is compared it should go into some loop for deactivatng a feature in only one site  in a bunch of webapp and activate in all other webapp. I have done with the code. But my condition if($site  -eq "url") is not taking me into the loop i debugged the code and checked both sides same url is only coming. thanks

Comment: Can you show us wat you already got?

Comment: What is in $site, the whole object or only the Url? You should do if($site.Url -eq "blabla") if you have the whole SPSite / SPWeb object stored in $site

Comment: Please provide the script you have already created.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this,

```
$URLa = "http....a"
$URLb = "http....b"

$c = $URLa.CompareTo($URLb)

if($c) ....
```

Comment: am comparing one particular url with all the site url eg: $site="myurl" in  foreach loop. So i cant hardcode the value for $site which is coming dynamically each turn. If required i will give my code what am using. Require suggestion.

Comment: You do not need to hardcode anything above, just store the values of each site URL from the objects you are retrieving in two variables..